# Determine whether a weak referenced object has been deallocated

Tags: objective-c, ios

I use the following code to download images:

```
- (void)downloadImageAtUrl:(id)url
               andDelegate:(id<IPServerDelegate>)delegate_ {
  NSURL *correctUrl = nil;
  if ([url isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    correctUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kHostURL, [url substringFromIndex:1]]];
  else
    correctUrl = url;
  __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:correctUrl];
  [imageRequestsArray addObject:request];
  [request setCompletionBlock:^{
    if (request.responseStatusCode == 200) {
      if (delegate_ && [delegate_ respondsToSelector:@selector(didDownloadImage:atUrl:)]) {
        [delegate_ didDownloadImage:request.responseData atUrl:request.url];
      }
    }
    else {
      if (delegate_ && [delegate_ respondsToSelector:@selector(failedToDownloadImageWithUrl:)]) {
        [delegate_ failedToDownloadImageWithUrl:request.url];
      }
    }
    [imageRequestsArray removeObject:request];
  }];

  [request setFailedBlock:^{
    if (delegate_ && [delegate_ respondsToSelector:@selector(failedToDownloadImageWithUrl:)]) {
      [delegate_ failedToDownloadImageWithUrl:request.url];
    }
    [imageRequestsArray removeObject:request];
  }];

  [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

If the delegate_ object has been deallocated the app crashes. How do I determine that the object delegate_ has been deallocated without having to create a direct reference to it? I know about __weak pointers in iOS 5, but my app must be compatible with iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution. I'm storing all the ASIHTTPRequest objects in the requests array. When any of my UIViewControllers is about to disappear (viewWillDisappear), I'm enumeration through the array and send cancel message to each of the request objects. The only inconvenience here is that those requests have to be resumed each time view appears again, but at least it's not crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when your delegate_ is deallocated, I assume that it is release. When it is, after:

```
[object release];
```

Do this:

```
object=nil;
```

On your code then, just check if it exists:

```
if(delegate_){

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not a solution. Just as I've said I must not have a direct reference to the delegate_ object, which is "object" in your answer.

Comment: Hummm, so at any moment you can end with a deallocated object?

Comment: Well then you have a problem. Humm. If we are talking about ASIHTTPRequest, I was able to edit their code source, and besides releasing the object, putting it to nil, so I could do things safer. You just need to check in their code source where that object would be released.

Comment: As seen from my question, I do not need to track ASIHTTPRequest objects. These must be different UIViewController objects.

Comment: Can't help you then. But would like to see an answer for this question. :) GL mate.